# AngularJS showing intermediate page while saving

Tags: angularjs

While saving a new invoice using my AngularJS app, there is a noticeable time taken while the API is checking products balances, saving data...etc so I was wondering is there a way in AngularJS where I can show like an intermediate (page...example: #/processing) where the users get routed to once the user click the `Save` button then depending on the save new invoice $http result (failure or success) either route the user back to the invoice page (ex. #/new-invoice) OR the success saving page (#/thanks-for-ordering) ?

Any example is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-if` to switch between a input and saving state.

Example template:

```
<div ng-if="isSaving"><img src="spinner.gif"> Saving...</div>
<form ng-if="!isSaving" ng-submit="saveTheThing(thing)>
   <input ng-model="thing.title" type="text"/>
   ...
</form>
```

Example controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('ExampleCtrl', function ($scope, $location) {

  $scope.saveTheThing = function(thing) {
    $scope.isSaving = true;
    $http.post('api/things', thing).then(function (response) {
        $location.path('/things/' + response.data.id); // Go to the success page
    }).catch(function (error) {
      $scope.error = error; // show error
    }).finally(function () {
      $scope.isSaving = false;
    });
  };
})
```

If you need IE8 support you'll need to replace `.catch` with `['catch']` and `.finally` with `['finally']`

Comment: Thanks for your help but I was looking more into routing to a different page...for example when clicking submit route from #/new-invoice >> to #/processing then upon success go to #/thanks-for-order OR #/new-invoice in case of error. Your solution will be great to show spinner on the same page

Answer (score 2):

i am using spinner for such things... on http request start the spinner and on response stop it. use the http interceptor for the same. if you dont want to implement it yourself, below are few links.

[angular-spinner](https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner) or [angular-sham-spinner](https://github.com/harinair/angular-sham-spinner)

also read this [BLOG](http://lemoncode.net/2013/07/31/angularjs-found-great-solution-to-display-ajax-spinner-loading-widget/) which details how the spinner works

Answer (score 1):

Although I wouldn't use a standalone url/route for a processing page. 
You can store the save promise in a service.

```
angular.module('app').value('progress', {});

angular.module('app').controller('FormCtrl', function ($scope, progress, $location) {

  $scope.saveTheThing = function(thing) {
    progress.thing = $http.post('api/things', thing);
    $location.path('/processing');
  });
});

angular.module('app').controller('ProgressingCtrl', function (progress, $location) {
   progress.thing.then(function () {
     $location.path('/thank-you');
   }, function (error) {
     $location.path('/form');
   });
});
```

Compared to the `ng-if` solution you now need additional work to:

- Restore the form values on failure
- Pass the error message to the FormCtrl
- Define the refresh behavior for the progressing page

Comment: Hmmm, so you believe that the best approach is to show spinner as (modal) to prevent interaction with the form from the user while processing then decide to either show error or success message?

Comment: I believe it's best to use one url/controller. How the page looks based on $scope.isSaving is totally up to you. And in combination with ng-include it's easy to have the progressing html in another template.